# UPDATE, DROP COLUMN and EXCEPT not working in Spark SQL

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm working on Spark SQL through Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool and when I use the **UPDATE** command the error I get is :

`UPDATE destination only supports Delta Sources.`

I tried dropping the column I wanted to update and then creating it from scratch but the **DROP COLUMN** command doesn't work either. The error I get is:

`DROP COLUMN is only supported with v2 tables.`

I also tried using the **EXCEPT** command to select all columns except the column I wanted to update. The command :

`SELECT * EXCEPT (NAME) FROM dummytable1;`

Even that produces an error :

`Syntax error at or near 'NAME'(line 1, pos 17)`

Is there some way to make any of these 3 commands work in Spark SQL through Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool? If so, please let me know.

Comment: The first two errors are pretty self-explanatory.  Are you working with delta files?  It doesn't sound like it to me.

Comment: Yeah I'm not working with delta files. Used CREATE TABLE command and added reqd values through INSERT INTO command. Is there no way to use UPDATE with non-delta lake files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure Synapse, when you use the **UPDATE** statement in **SPARK SQL**, it is designed to work with Delta Lake tables.
If you try to use the **UPDATE** statement on a non-Delta table, you will get this error.

As you asked for the way to use UPDATE with non-delta lake files You can use pyspark code instead
As an example I have created a student_table

[image]

As you can see I have updated the record for Grade in the Below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
studentsDF = studentsDF.withColumn("Grade",
when(col("Name") == "Bob", "F Failed")
.otherwise(col("Grade"))
)
studentsDF.show()
```

[image]

In Azure Synapse, the **DROP COLUMN** operation is supported only on v2 (version 2) tables. V2 tables are the newer version of tables in Synapse Analytics that offer improved performance and additional features compared to the original version.

The below code in pyspark will help you **DROP** a column.

```
selectedStudentsDF = selectedStudentsDF.drop("Age")
selectedStudentsDF.show()
```

[image]

For Except this error occurs because the **EXCEPT** statement in SPARK SQL does not support the syntax **SELECT * EXCEPT (column_name)**. The correct syntax for **EXCEPT** is `SELECT * FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM table2`

In pyspark you can use the Exceptall

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
allStudentsDF = studentsDF
bobDF = studentsDF.filter(col("Name") == "Bob")
selectedStudentsDF = allStudentsDF.exceptAll(bobDF)
selectedStudentsDF.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, tried this workaround and it worked.